# Can't install ruby to /usr/local on Ubuntu 14.04 using rbenv

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

Have to re-install ruby on our server because our Rails installation is failing (some OpenSSL error). 
I successfully uninstalled it by running `$sudo rm -rf $(rbenv prefix 1.9.3-p194)` Because the command `rbenv uninstall` failed. Then I couldn't `$rbenv rehash` because:

`rbenv: cannot rehash: /usr/local/rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim exists`

But I'm not sure if that matters.

Anyways now when I try to run `$rbenv install -v 1.9.3-p194` I get a permission denied error:

`cannot create directory '/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194': Permission denied`

But when I run `$sudo rbenv install -v 1.9.3-p194` the ruby is installed successfully in `/home/anbranin/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194`, which is NOT where it's supposed to be, right? It's supposed to be in `/usr/local`.

Total newbie here trying to run a legacy rails application--our devops person is out--so I'm lacking in knowledge about Linux servers.

My only idea at this point is to just `sudo mv` the files to `usr/local` but will that work?

Comment: No it will not work. Ruby has hardcoded paths for its libraries at compile time.

Comment: No that's the correct path - rbenv uses shims, which are within the `.rbenv` directory in your home directory